Wine and rcedit not working for mac, to export for windows 2024
Tested on Godot Version: Godot 4.2.2, Godot 4.3.beta1
MacBook: Macbook pro M2 pro; Sonoma 14.5 (23F79)
I already install wine (wine-9.0) using brew, also downloaded redit-x64.exe from here. Godot try to change the icon and other stuff it stuck and basically exit out and spit out this log
rcedit (../Builds/mygame/windows/mygame.tmp): 008c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
008c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
008c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
008c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
wine: failed to open "../Builds/mygame/windows/mygame.tmp": c0000135
Rcedit v2.0.0: Edit resources of exe.

Usage: rcedit <filename> [options...]

Options:
  -h, --help                                 Show this message
  --set-version-string <key> <value>         Set version string
  --get-version-string <key>                 Print version string
  --set-file-version <version>               Set FileVersion
  --set-product-version <version>            Set ProductVersion
  --set-icon <path-to-icon>                  Set file icon
  --set-requested-execution-level <level>    Pass nothing to see usage
  --application-manifest <path-to-file>      Set manifest file
  --set-resource-string <key> <value>        Set resource string
  --get-resource-string <key>                Get resource string
  --set-rcdata <key> <path-to-file>          Replace RCDATA by integer id
002c:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetProcessTerminationMethod FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA, 000000000011FE80

rcedit (../Builds/mygame/windows/mygame.console.exe): 008c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
008c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
008c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
008c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
wine: failed to open "../Builds/mygame/windows/mygame.console.exe": c0000135
Rcedit v2.0.0: Edit resources of exe.

Usage: rcedit <filename> [options...]

Options:
  -h, --help                                 Show this message
  --set-version-string <key> <value>         Set version string
  --get-version-string <key>                 Print version string
  --set-file-version <version>               Set FileVersion
  --set-product-version <version>            Set ProductVersion
  --set-icon <path-to-icon>                  Set file icon
  --set-requested-execution-level <level>    Pass nothing to see usage
  --application-manifest <path-to-file>      Set manifest file
  --set-resource-string <key> <value>        Set resource string
  --get-resource-string <key>                Get resource string
  --set-rcdata <key> <path-to-file>          Replace RCDATA by integer id
002c:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetProcessTerminationMethod FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA, 000000000011FE80

I also installed winetricks vcrun2015
Does any body export game for windows from mac using wine and rcedit. If there is other way please give me suggestion or tutorial would be nice
thank you
